# how to redefine column in Blueprint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

### Background

I am trying to extend class Blueprint to make my Blueprint.Finally,I found the way .But when I made attempt to overwrite some ColumnDefinition ,some trouble stopped me.

### Problem 1

```php
 Schema::create('Person',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->string('id')->comment('身份证号');
    $table->string('id')->comment('学号')->change();//this line doesn't work!
});
```

Like the code above,the second line in that Closure doesn't work and i don't know why.

What I know is that some 'Modify Cloumn' operations need a dependency called `doctrine/dbal` and I have installed it.

The function `change()` neither reports any error nor meets expectation.It is strange.

Please help me!

### Problem 2

By reading the source code of `Schema`,I found the relationship between `Schema` and `Blueprint` is `Schema->Builder->Blueprint`.`Schema::create()` will call `$blueprint->create()` before the `Closure function(Blueprint $table)`.It seems that it is the same effect whether I define the fields in the `Closure` or directly put the field definitions in the `$blueprint->__constructor()`.But,when I run `migrate`,the `Blueprint`'s `constructor` is called more than once.If I put all of the column definitions in that `Closure`,everyting is fine.Strange!

And,I also noticed that `$table->unique()` finally becomes `alter table $table add unique`,why not compile command before creating like `create table $table(...,unique key $keyname (k1,k2,))`.

At present,I believe that Blueprint saves column definitions in a array `$commands[]` and finally compiles the commands into `sql`.If so,why not support overwrite when before table is created?

Comment: Why are you changing the column you're creating? Couldn't you just use `$table->string('id')->comment('学号');`? It might not be working correctly as this is `Schema::create()` (which creates the table), and not `Schema::table()` (which modifies the table).

Comment: In order to ask questions easily, I simplified the original problem. In fact, the feature I want to implement is Blueprint's class inheritance. For example, `Class Person extends Blueprint`, and `Class Student extends Person`. So if I want to override the parent class `Person's field definition in `Student`, what should I do?